# Algorithm: Selecting common elements of a collection

Tags: algorithm, performance, language-agnostic

I recently had to write the following algorithm:

> Given a group of tags, and a group of
>   blog posts, where a blog post may
>   contain zero-to-many tags, return the
>   tags common to all posts.

This comparison is being done in-memory - accessing either collection **does not** cause a trip across the network (ie., to a database, etc).

Also, the `Tags` collection does not have a reference to `BlogPosts` that contain it.  `BlogPosts` have a collection of `Tags` they contain.

Below is my implementation.  It performs just fine, but I'm curious if there was a better way to implement it.

My implementation is in Actionscript, but I'm curious more from a algorithim perspective, so examples in any language is fine.  (But if I don't know the language, I may ask you to clarify some aspects)

Any examples of improvements would be greatly received.

```
    private function getCommonTags(blogPosts:Vector.<BlogPost>):Vector.<Tag>
    {
        var commonTags:Vector.<Tag> = new Vector.<Tag>();
        if (!blogPosts || blogPosts.length == 0)
            return commonTags;

        var blogPost:BlogPost = blogPosts[0];
        if (!blogPost.tags || blogPost.tags.length == 0)
            return commonTags;

        commonTags = Vector.<Tag>(blogPosts[0].tags);

        for each (var blogPost:BlogPost in blogPosts)
        {
            if (!blogPost.tags || blogPost.tags.length == 0 || commonTags.length == 0)
                // Updated to fix bug mentioned below
                // Optomized exit - there are no common tags
                return new Vector.<Tag>();

            for each (var tag:Tag in commonTags)
            {
                if (!blogPost.containsTagId(tag.id))
                {
                    commonTags.splice(commonTags.indexOf(tag),1);
                }
            }
        }
        return commonTags;
    }
```

Comment: I don't know Actionscript, but this code will run faster if you can cheaply order the blogposts by blogPost.tags.length. Also I think there's a bug when the first post has 2 tags and the second 0, it will return the 2 tags of the first post.

Comment: @krusty.ar Thanks!  Sorting by the number of tags is a great idea.  I think the bug you mention is from some poor variable renaming on my behalf - I've edit the code, let me know if you still see the bug (I don't).

Comment: Ok, suppose blogPosts[0].tags.lenght == 2 and blogPosts[0].tags.lenght == 0, the first pass of the for each loop will compare the 2 tags of the first post with the 2 tags of the first post, wich are identical, so commonTags.lenght == 2, in the second pass of the loop, blogPost.tags.length == 0, so the "optimized exit" is used, but still commonTags.lenght == 2, so you are returning the tags of the first post, wich the second post doesn't have, the correct version would be something like return new Vector.<Tag>();

Comment: You're absolutely correct.  Thanks - I'll fix that.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you just need an efficient algorithm for computing the intersection of two sets because you can just repeatedly invoke the algorithm for more than two sets.

A quick algorithm is to add the items of the first set to a hash table and then iterate through the second set checking the hash table to see if it is present; if it is you add it to the list of items to be returned in the intersection.

Answer (score 0):

I can state this program in an English sentence: "Return all tags that occur uniformly among the posts."

Giving the name `all_tags` to the list of tags and `post_tags` to the list of tags-associated-to-posts, I can say the same thing with this sentence in the [J programming language](http://www.jsoftware.com/)

```
   all_tags #~ (#=+/) all_tags e.&>"_ 0 post_tags
```

Looking at this in some detail:

- `#~` means "copy where"
- `(# = +/)` means "tally equals sum"
- `e.` means "exists in"
- `&>"_ 0` modifies `e.` so the entirety of `all_tags` is compared with each of the tag-sets in `post_tags`

If we want to make this a program that takes two arguments, rather than a program that is specific to these named lists, the corresponding program could be:

```
   common_to=:  [ #~ [:(#=+/) [ e.&>"_ 0 ]
```

Running that program with the same data names would look like this:

```
   all_tags common_to post_tags
```

It seems worth noting that we don't actually need the comprehensive list of tags, as that can be derived. (The calculation is `~. ; post_tags`.) That means we could write the program to take only a single argument. But since the problem presumes we already have the `all_tags` list computed, there's no need to compute it again.